# more SEO friendly head

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a movie database related site. In this we are providing latest movie news, trailers, movie database, posters etc.

I am using a 124 chars long 3 sentences meta description as the index page's meta description. And a 6 phrase meta keywords also. ( in index page ) and showing the same description and keywords in all the other pages.

My doubt is, would I need to give the different description and keywords to other pages in the site ? i.e., diff description for latest movie page, like diff desc for latest news page ?

I am very new to SEO and which one is more SEO friendly? The same description or different for diff pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use keywords and description according to the content you are serving with any URL.

If your page is serving the news of a newly released movie set your keywords and description related to that movie.

You can build a functionality in your administration where these values can be entered dynamically to each article you serve and display them in your html head

Comment: thanks zamil for your reply .. i.e dynamic description and keywords wont affect the SEO ranking ? Am I correct ? I can use description according to each page ?

Comment: @ramesh:do not attempt to change keywords and description frequently for a URL.That will never do good.Spend some minutes here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34439

Comment: thanks for the reply ... I mean Can I use separate descriptions for news section, latest movie reviews , forum etc ? That will follow its sub-pages.. is this the correct way ?

Comment: yes u can use separate descriptions,but it should match the content served